# Minecraft not starting

Tags: c#, minecraft

I am in a project of a launcher minecraft, but without using java! only C#.

I have this code but do not know what's going wrong, just the java open but then closes.

```
public void RunMinecraft()
    {
        List<string> j_args = new List<string>();
        List<string> libraries = new List<string>();

        args = "";

        int x = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);
        j_args.Add("-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump");
        j_args.Add("-Xmx" + x + "G");
        j_args.Add("-Djava.library.path=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\natives");
        j_args.Add("net.minecraft.client.main.Main");
        string lib = Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\libraries\\{0}";
        string app = Application.StartupPath;
        string game = Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\game";
        string assets = Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\assets";

        #region LIBRARIES
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "oshi-core-1.1.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "jna-3.4.0.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "platform-3.4.0.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "jopt-simple-4.6.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "codecjorbis-20101023.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "codecwav-20101023.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "libraryjavasound-20101123.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "soundsystem-20120107.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "guava-17.0.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "commons-io-2.4.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "commons-codec-1.9.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "jinput-2.0.5.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "jutils-1.0.0.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "gson-2.2.4.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "authlib-1.5.21.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "realms-1.7.48.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "httpcore-4.3.2.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format2(lib, "log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar"));
        libraries.Add(format3(lib, "1.8.6.jar"));
        #endregion

        var librariesSTR = "";

        var enum0 = libraries.GetEnumerator();
        while (enum0.MoveNext())
        {
            librariesSTR += enum0.Current;
        }

        j_args.Add("-cp " + librariesSTR);
        j_args.Add("--username " + username.Text);
        j_args.Add("--accessToken " + accesstoken.Text);
        j_args.Add("--userProperties {}");
        j_args.Add("--version 1.8.6");
        j_args.Add("--gameDir " + game);

        var argsSTR = "";
        var enum1 = j_args.GetEnumerator();
        while (enum1.MoveNext())
        {
            argsSTR += enum1.Current + " ";
        }

        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe";
        info.Arguments = args;

        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        info.RedirectStandardError = true;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.OutputDataReceived += P_OutputDataReceived;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();

        // Clipboard.SetText(argsSTR);
    }

    private string format3(string a, string b)
    {
        return string.Format(a, b);
    }

    #region format2
    private string format2(string a, string b)
    {
        return string.Format(a, b) + ";";
    }
    #endregion
```

I use the format2 function to cause it to the formatting of all the libraries correctly. Example:

```
libraries.Add("unnamed_lib1.jar"); libraries.Add ("unnamed_lib2.jar");
```

the result will look like this:

```
args = "unnamed_lib1.jar;unnamed_lib2.jar;";
```

And the function format3(string a, string b); is the event to finish with the JAR file of the game.
Example: "1.8.9.jar" without the ';' at the end

> **Sorry for the misspelling because I do not speak much English. And I am using Google translator to help me with the texts.
>
>
>   I'm using the 1.8.6 version of minecraft to start**

Comment: please remove `java` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `-cp` (classpath) arguments before `net.minecraft.client.main.Main` , or they will be considered arguments for the application (`Main` class), not for the `javaw` executable.

It would be something like (I wrote only some of your arguments, ommited java.exe and maybe other things) :

```
j_args.Add("-XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump");
j_args.Add("-Xmx" + x + "G");
j_args.Add("-Djava.library.path=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\natives");
j_args.Add("-cp " + librariesSTR);
j_args.Add("net.minecraft.client.main.Main");
j_args.Add("--username " + username.Text);
j_args.Add("--accessToken " + accesstoken.Text);
j_args.Add("--userProperties {}");
j_args.Add("--version 1.8.6");
j_args.Add("--gameDir " + game);
```

Comment: It was not too! I tried to redirect the process for a TextBox to see the contents of the java window but it was not

Comment: java.exe and javaw.exe should both work. You may try your command in a DOS shell, you will see the errors .

Comment: The libraries must be in the correct order or can be random

Comment: They may be random, no problem.

Comment: Glad I will try to do the research of jar files and try to add all and reduce code. I just searched the internet but it says nothing could be random or not so I was a little doubtful about it

Comment: It did not work : (  java opens and closes quickly when click play

Comment: Just ouptut the whole command line, and paste the command in a DOS shell  (launch cmd.exe to get one).

Comment: Cmd says "Could not find or load the main class Ferreira\Documents\Visual"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100073/discussion-between-berger-and-user3661031).